# Google App Script - setId on Component not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a UI for a spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get an ID to set on any Component when using the UiService. I can verify the ID is not set using the Chrome developer tools. It may or may not be relevant, but I'm using Drive in in a Google Apps for Domain environment. Here is the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Tweet Menu')
      .addItem('Tweet Sidebar', 'tweetSidebar')
      .addToUi();
};

function tweetSidebar() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle('Tweet Sidebar');

  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.setId('twitterPanel');
  panel.setStyleAttribute('margin', '5px');

  var textArea = app.createTextArea();
  textArea.setId('12345');
  textArea.setName('tweetText');
  textArea.setWidth('290px').setHeight('175px');

  var keyPressHandler = app.createServerHandler('checkLength');
  keyPressHandler.addCallbackElement(textArea);
  textArea.addKeyPressHandler(keyPressHandler)

  var button = app.createButton('Add Tweet');
  button.setId('addTweet');

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('addTweet');
  handler.addCallbackElement(textArea);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  panel.add(textArea);
  panel.add(button);

  app.add(panel);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(app);
}

function addTweet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var textAreaValue = e.parameter.tweetText;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var previousBufferID = sheet.getRange('b' + lastRow);
  var newBufferID = previousBufferID.getValue() + 1;
  var lastTweetCell = sheet.getRange('a' + (lastRow + 1));
  var lastBufferID = sheet.getRange('b' + (lastRow + 1));
  lastTweetCell.setValue(textAreaValue);
  lastBufferID.setValue(newBufferID);
  app.getElementById('12345').setValue('');
}

function checkLength(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var textAreaValue = e.parameter.tweetText;
  var len = textAreaValue.length;
  app.getElementById('12345');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing `return app;` in the checkLength() and addTweet() functions.

Comment: I added that in, but it doesn't seem to have changed the behavior in anyway. I've since ported the app from a spreadsheet sidebar to a Google Apps Script web app. The code returns the proper element when I call app.getElementById, but it still doesn't add an 'id' attribute to any of the elements in the HTML output.